# Given $n\geq 0, j\geq 1.$ How many solutions to: $\sum_{i=1}^j x_i=n,$ where $x_i\geq 0$ and $x_i$ are all different?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, diophantine-equations

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\},\ j\in\mathbb{N}.$ How many solutions are there to: $\sum_{i=1}^j x_i=n,$ where $x_i\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,j\}$ and $x_k\neq x_l$ if $k\neq l\ ?$

Without this restriction:

$x_k\neq x_l$ if $k\neq l,$

the stars and bars method gives the answer $\binom{j-1+n}{j-1},$ as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2271829).

I was wondering if some clever trick can answer my question with the restriction in place.

$x_1=2, x_2=0$ and $x_1=0, x_2=2$ are two different solutions. Although considering these to be the same would be another interesting question. But let's leave this question for another day...

Comment: Is $j$ given as well or do you want the number of solutions when $j$ takes all possible vaues?

Comment: @Gribouillis yes $j$ is given. I've updated the question.

Comment: Aha, that makes it easier.

Comment: This seems to be $j!$ times the number of partitions of $n+j$ into $j$ distinct parts. AFAIK the latter has no closed formula.

Comment: @aschepler by adding $1$ to each part, there is a bijection between “the partitions of $n$ into $j$ distinct nonnegative parts” and “the partitions of $n+j$ into $j$ distinct (positive) parts”.

Comment: and I think this is $j!$ times the number of partitions of $n-\frac{j(j-1)}{2}$ into no more than $j$ parts (or $j!$ times the number of partitions of $n-\frac{j(j-1)}{2}$ into parts no larger than $j$)